# retry function is not working for more than 3 count

Tags: dsl, karate

I am using retry in my code to check the GET status and I retry the hit until I get 200.

my code is :

```
Given configure retry = { interval: 5000 , attempts: 5 }
And  URL 
And  param query = 'name:' + title
And def auth = callonce 
read('classpath:examples/Tokens/ViewToken.feature') 
{'viewAccessToken': 'viewAccessToken' }
And print ' view token', auth.viewAccessToken
And header Authorization = auth.viewAccessToken
And retry until responseStatus == 200
```

When method get.

But this works only for 3 counts even though I have set the retry count to 5.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* configure retry = { count: 5, interval: 5000 }
```